# Skip subentity of abstract entity and just implement subclasses programatically?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a core data abstract entity which is backed by a class that's subclassed for many concrete [sub]entities that I create and manipulate instances of.  No attributes or relationships or properties are different in the subclasses.  I'm just overriding method implementations. So other then setting the subclass and parent entity, the xcdatamodeld is empty for each subentity.

If there are no unique properties or relationships in the subentities in xcdatamodeld, and I'm creating quite a number of them, is there some code that I could create in the abstract superentity class to handle the core data subentity registration?

What I'm looking for is some *reasonable* code that lets me just create a .h/.m for each new subentity (which subclasses the abstract entity, which subclasses NSManagedObject), and skip seemingly duplicate and cluttering work in xcdatamodeld of +entity, edit name, add class, declare parent entity.  Is this feasible and reasonable?  Or do I go down a rabbit hole of arcane programmatic managedObjectModel editing outside of my class implementations?

[edit] To add background about why subclasses.  One-- each subclass creates a different tree of child entities.  Two-- each subclass assembles its data differently for passing to views.   ie they all have the same string properties, but each subclass might present an attributedStringForTitle differently than the next.

Comment: You may be better off describing why you have so many different accessor method implementations...

Comment: Added detail above.  Not accessors per se.   Each subclass object is the root of a different tree, and each subclass object may assemble its properties differently for views.  Edit added above.

Comment: What dictates which subclass is used? Why not a type attribute / object state pattern controller?

Comment: Polymorphism dictates. There is a class of entities with a to-one relation to an object of the abstract entity.  Depending on which subclass the relation resolves to, the correctly overridden methods are invoked.  I do think I clearly want polymorphism. Having a type attribute and something like a switch{} seems even clunkier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the closest you will get is by using [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/). You may be able to script changes to the data model, but unless you're going to create lots of classes then it likely won't save you time.

Comment: Endorsed just because I'm already using mogenerator and would recommend it in a heartbeat.   I think this question arose because I'd just rather use xcdatamodeld as little as possible and get down to code for these subclasses.  But I do actually have mogenerator trigger off the new empty entities and create the subclasses for me.  WAY too much going on behind the scenes out of the scope of code, but I guess that's what I've signed up for with core data.